# Swift: UInt Memory & Performance dependent on value?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, int, uint

First of all, please excuse the stupid question. I believe that it makes no difference, but I'd just like to be sure. *Int32* can handle values up to 2147483647, and *UInt64* up to 18446744073709551615.

**Q:** *In iOS, under Swift, does it make any difference, **in memory or performance,** if large values were used in object tags, say 100,000?*

Comment: How is the first paragraph related to your question?

Comment: @Sweeper: In iOS, object tags utilise the *Int* type.